# Template Name and call-template

Tags: xslt-1.0

i have xslt for change status transaction. i can change for template who was in scope at template name bodys. but the plan was when data on headers have failed some condition and the status  for the template bodys in node TxRsnSts need change too. but i cant get the value from headers. how i can get the value from headers and submit on variable name TxRsnStsB.

This the XSLT script i make

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:ns1="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" xmlns:ns2="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.002.001.10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output indent="no" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <ns:BusMsg xmlns:ns="urn:iso" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso ../../../xsd/phase1/MainCIHub.xsd">
                <ns1:AppHdr>
                    <xsl:call-template name="headers">
                        <xsl:with-param name="CpyDplct" select="//BusMsg/AppHdr/CpyDplct"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="PssblDplct" select="//BusMsg/AppHdr/PssblDplct"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="Sgntr" select="//BusMsg/AppHdr/Sgntr"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </ns1:AppHdr>
                <ns:Document>
                    <ns:FIToFIPmtStsRpt>
                        <xsl:call-template name="bodys">
                            <xsl:with-param name="CtgyPurpB" select="//BusMsg/Document/FItoFICstmrCdtTrf/CdtTrfTxInf/PmtTpInf/CtgyPurp/Prtry"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="IntrBkSttlmAmtB" select="//BusMsg/Document/FItoFICstmrCdtTrf/CdtTrfTxInf/IntrBkSttlmAmt/Value"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="CcyB" select="//BusMsg/Document/FItoFICstmrCdtTrf/CdtTrfTxInf/IntrBkSttlmAmt/Ccy"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </ns:FIToFIPmtStsRpt>
                </ns:Document>
            </ns:BusMsg>
        </xsl:template>
        
        <xsl:template name="headers">
            <xsl:param name="CpyDplct"/>
            <xsl:param name="PssblDplct"/>
            <xsl:param name="Sgntr"/>
            <xsl:variable name="flagCpyDplcts">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$CpyDplct = ''"/>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length($CpyDplct) &lt;= 35 and ($CpyDplct = 'CODU' or $CpyDplct = 'COPY' or $CpyDplct = 'DUPL')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$CpyDplct"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$CpyDplct"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'U0002'"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            
            <xsl:variable name="flagPssblDplcts">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$PssblDplct = ''"/>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length($PssblDplct) &lt;= 35 and ($PssblDplct = 'true' or $PssblDplct = 'false')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$PssblDplct"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$PssblDplct"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'U0002'"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="flagSgntrs">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$Sgntr = ''"/>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length($Sgntr) &lt;= 35">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$Sgntr"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$PssblDplct"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'U0012'"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <ns1:CpyDplct>
                <xsl:value-of select="$flagCpyDplcts"/>
            </ns1:CpyDplct>
            <ns1:PssblDplct>
                <xsl:value-of select="$flagPssblDplcts"/>
            </ns1:PssblDplct>
            <ns1:Sgntr>
                <xsl:value-of select="$flagSgntrs"/>
            </ns1:Sgntr>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="bodys">
            <xsl:param name="CtgyPurpB"/>
            <xsl:param name="IntrBkSttlmAmtB"/>
            <xsl:param name="CcyB"/>
            <xsl:variable name="flagCtgyPurpBs">
                <xsl:variable name="payT" select="substring($CtgyPurpB,1,3)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="catP" select="substring($CtgyPurpB,4,2)"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(contains($payT,'010') or contains($payT,'011') or contains($payT,'019') or contains($payT,'110') or contains($payT,'510') or contains($payT,'610') or contains($payT,'710') or contains($payT,'720') or contains($payT,'000'))">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'U0002'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="not(contains($catP,'01') or contains($catP,'02') or contains($catP,'03') or contains($catP,'99'))">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'U0002'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$CtgyPurpB"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="flagIntrBkSttlmAmtBs">
                <xsl:variable name="amount" select="substring-before($IntrBkSttlmAmtB,'.')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="decimal" select="substring-after($IntrBkSttlmAmtB,'.')"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(fn:matches($IntrBkSttlmAmtB, '^[0-9.]*$'))">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'U0038'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="not(string-length($amount) &lt;= 16)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'U0038'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="not(string-length($decimal) &lt;= 2)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'U0038'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$IntrBkSttlmAmtB"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="flagCcyBs">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(fn:matches($CcyB, '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$') and string-length($CcyB) &lt;= 3)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'U0038'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$CcyB"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <ns1:CtgyPurp>
                <xsl:value-of select="$flagCtgyPurpBs"/>
            </ns1:CtgyPurp>
            <ns1:IntrBkSttlmAmt>
                <xsl:value-of select="$flagIntrBkSttlmAmtBs"/>
            </ns1:IntrBkSttlmAmt>
            <ns1:Ccy>
                <xsl:value-of select="$flagCcyBs"/>
            </ns1:Ccy>
            <xsl:variable name="TxRsnStsB">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when
                        test="contains($flagSgntrs, 'U0012') or contains($flagSgntrs, 'U0002') or contains($flagSgntrs, 'U0038') or contains($flagPssblDplcts, 'U0012') or contains($flagPssblDplcts, 'U0002') or contains($flagPssblDplcts, 'U0038') or contains($flagCpyDplcts, 'U0012') or contains($flagCpyDplcts, 'U0002') or contains($flagCpyDplcts, 'U0038') or contains($flagCtgyPurpBs, 'U0012') or contains($flagCtgyPurpBs, 'U0002') or contains($flagCtgyPurpBs, 'U0038')      or contains($flagIntrBkSttlmAmtBs, 'U0012') or contains($flagIntrBkSttlmAmtBs, 'U0002') or contains($flagIntrBkSttlmAmtBs, 'U0038') or contains($flagCcyBs, 'U0012') or contains($flagCcyBs, 'U0002') or contains($flagCcyBs, 'U0038')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Decline'" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Approve'" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <ns1:TxRsnSts><xsl:value-of select="$TxRsnStsB"/></ns1:TxRsnSts>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand.
If you want to reuse the variabels you have declared in headers inside body, you have two options:
Save the result of headers inside a variable and use that as a parameter in your call to bodys.
The other option is to declare those variables as globals like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
  xmlns:ns1="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" 
  xmlns:ns2="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.002.001.10" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="no" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="CpyDplct" select="//BusMsg/AppHdr/CpyDplct"/>
  <xsl:variable name="PssblDplct" select="//BusMsg/AppHdr/PssblDplct"/>
  <xsl:variable name="Sgntr" select="//BusMsg/AppHdr/Sgntr"/>

  <xsl:variable name="flagCpyDplcts">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$CpyDplct = ''"/>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($CpyDplct) &lt;= 35 and ($CpyDplct = 'CODU' or $CpyDplct = 'COPY' or $CpyDplct = 'DUPL')">
        <xsl:value-of select="$CpyDplct"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$CpyDplct"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="'U0002'"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:variable name="flagPssblDplcts">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$PssblDplct = ''"/>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($PssblDplct) &lt;= 35 and ($PssblDplct = 'true' or $PssblDplct = 'false')">
        <xsl:value-of select="$PssblDplct"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$PssblDplct"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="'U0002'"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:variable name="flagSgntrs">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$Sgntr = ''"/>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($Sgntr) &lt;= 35">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Sgntr"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$PssblDplct"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="'U0012'"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns:BusMsg xmlns:ns="urn:iso" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso ../../../xsd/phase1/MainCIHub.xsd">
      <ns1:AppHdr>
        <xsl:call-template name="headers"/>
      </ns1:AppHdr>
      <ns:Document>
        <ns:FIToFIPmtStsRpt>
          <xsl:call-template name="bodys">
            <xsl:with-param name="CtgyPurpB" select="//BusMsg/Document/FItoFICstmrCdtTrf/CdtTrfTxInf/PmtTpInf/CtgyPurp/Prtry"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="IntrBkSttlmAmtB" select="//BusMsg/Document/FItoFICstmrCdtTrf/CdtTrfTxInf/IntrBkSttlmAmt/Value"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="CcyB" select="//BusMsg/Document/FItoFICstmrCdtTrf/CdtTrfTxInf/IntrBkSttlmAmt/Ccy"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </ns:FIToFIPmtStsRpt>
      </ns:Document>
    </ns:BusMsg>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template name="headers">
    <ns1:CpyDplct>
      <xsl:value-of select="$flagCpyDplcts"/>
    </ns1:CpyDplct>
    <ns1:PssblDplct>
      <xsl:value-of select="$flagPssblDplcts"/>
    </ns1:PssblDplct>
    <ns1:Sgntr>
      <xsl:value-of select="$flagSgntrs"/>
    </ns1:Sgntr>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template name="bodys">
    <xsl:param name="CtgyPurpB"/>
    <xsl:param name="IntrBkSttlmAmtB"/>
    <xsl:param name="CcyB"/>
    <xsl:param name="header"/>
    <xsl:variable name="flagCtgyPurpBs">
      <xsl:variable name="payT" select="substring($CtgyPurpB,1,3)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="catP" select="substring($CtgyPurpB,4,2)"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($payT,'010') or contains($payT,'011') or contains($payT,'019') or contains($payT,'110') or contains($payT,'510') or contains($payT,'610') or contains($payT,'710') or contains($payT,'720') or contains($payT,'000'))">
          <xsl:value-of select="'U0002'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($catP,'01') or contains($catP,'02') or contains($catP,'03') or contains($catP,'99'))">
          <xsl:value-of select="'U0002'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$CtgyPurpB"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="flagIntrBkSttlmAmtBs">
      <xsl:variable name="amount" select="substring-before($IntrBkSttlmAmtB,'.')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="decimal" select="substring-after($IntrBkSttlmAmtB,'.')"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(fn:matches($IntrBkSttlmAmtB, '^[0-9.]*$'))">
          <xsl:value-of select="'U0038'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not(string-length($amount) &lt;= 16)">
          <xsl:value-of select="'U0038'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not(string-length($decimal) &lt;= 2)">
          <xsl:value-of select="'U0038'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$IntrBkSttlmAmtB"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="flagCcyBs">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(fn:matches($CcyB, '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$') and string-length($CcyB) &lt;= 3)">
          <xsl:value-of select="'U0038'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$CcyB"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <ns1:CtgyPurp>
      <xsl:value-of select="$flagCtgyPurpBs"/>
    </ns1:CtgyPurp>
    <ns1:IntrBkSttlmAmt>
      <xsl:value-of select="$flagIntrBkSttlmAmtBs"/>
    </ns1:IntrBkSttlmAmt>
    <ns1:Ccy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$flagCcyBs"/>
    </ns1:Ccy>
    <xsl:variable name="TxRsnStsB">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($flagSgntrs, 'U0012') or contains($flagSgntrs, 'U0002') or contains($flagSgntrs, 'U0038') or contains($flagPssblDplcts, 'U0012') or contains($flagPssblDplcts, 'U0002') or contains($flagPssblDplcts, 'U0038') or contains($flagCpyDplcts, 'U0012') or contains($flagCpyDplcts, 'U0002') or contains($flagCpyDplcts, 'U0038') or contains($flagCtgyPurpBs, 'U0012') or contains($flagCtgyPurpBs, 'U0002') or contains($flagCtgyPurpBs, 'U0038')      or contains($flagIntrBkSttlmAmtBs, 'U0012') or contains($flagIntrBkSttlmAmtBs, 'U0002') or contains($flagIntrBkSttlmAmtBs, 'U0038') or contains($flagCcyBs, 'U0012') or contains($flagCcyBs, 'U0002') or contains($flagCcyBs, 'U0038')">
          <xsl:value-of select="'Decline'" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="'Approve'" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <ns1:TxRsnSts><xsl:value-of select="$TxRsnStsB"/></ns1:TxRsnSts>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```